# How to write query for a column in joining

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select top 2  
    CONVERT(varchar(6),a.lastdate,6) as lastdate
    ,(select name from table_states where ID=a.joblocation ) as locat
    ,* 
from table_jobpost as a 
inner join (select * 
            from table_SuperAdmin as b 
            inner join table_Renewal as c on b.S_id=c.supid 
            where **c.proid** in (select [plan] 
                                    from table_features 
                                    where Fjobs=1) 
            and c.Payed=1) as aa on a.oid=aa.businessid 
where a.status=1 
and a.lastdate>GETDATE() 
order by startdate desc
```

In the above query `c.proid` I want like:

```
select top 1 proid from table_Renewal  order by renewalid desc
```

How can I rearrange the query ?

Right now in `c.proid` I have more than one id.so it will will check for all ids. I want to check only for

```
select top 1 proid from table_Renewal  order by renewalid desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether i have understood your question correctly. but see my answer below

**select max(proid) from table_Renewal**

can you try this

select top 2
    CONVERT(varchar(6),a.lastdate,6) as lastdate
    ,(select name from table_states where ID=a.joblocation ) as locat
    ,* 
from table_jobpost as a 
inner join (select * 
            from table_SuperAdmin as b 
            inner join table_Renewal as c on b.S_id=c.supid 
**left outer join (select max(proid) as proid1,supid from table_Renewal group by supid) as c1 on b.S_id=c1.supid 
            where c1.proid1** in (select [plan] 
                                    from table_features 
                                    where Fjobs=1) 
            and c.Payed=1) as aa on a.oid=aa.businessid 
where a.status=1 
and a.lastdate>GETDATE() 
order by startdate desc

Comment: sir how i can write the same on the place of c.proid in above query